# SQL: Group and count both masters & details

Tags: sql, t-sql

I want to count mails sent (master table: ex_deliverylog) & their recipients (details table: ex_deliverylog) from logs. The query below returns same values for both [session] and [recipients]. In short I couldn't group & count [session].

```
    Select 
        deliveryaccount,
        DATEDIFF(d,deliverytime, getdate()) AS ago
        ,COUNT(ex_deliverylog.deliveryid) as session
        ,COUNT(ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryid) as recipients

        --,( select count(*) from ex_deliverylog_recipients where ex_deliverylog.deliveryid = ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryid )  

    from ex_deliverylog

    left join ex_deliverylog_recipients 
           on ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryid = ex_deliverylog.deliveryid


    group by
        deliveryaccount,
        DATEDIFF(d,deliverytime, getdate())


    order by ago, session desc
```

Query & result:

[image]

Tables & fields:

[image]

How can I count both sessions & their total recipients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you are trying to do, I think you need to use `COUNT DISTINCT` on the count of sessions instead of just `COUNT` which defaults to `COUNT ALL`:

```
SELECT 
        deliveryaccount,
        DATEDIFF(d,deliverytime, getdate()) AS ago
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT ex_deliverylog.deliveryid) as session
        ,COUNT(ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryid) as recipients
FROM ex_deliverylog
LEFT JOIN ex_deliverylog_recipients 
       ON ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryid = ex_deliverylog.deliveryid
GROUP BY
    deliveryaccount,
    DATEDIFF(d,deliverytime, getdate())
ORDER BY ago, session desc
```

That way, the session count will reflect the number of distinct sessions and the recipient count will reflect the number of distinct recipients. When neither `ALL` nor `DISTINCT` is specified, `COUNT` defaults to `ALL` and you get the behavior you are experiencing (i.e., the same count for both).

Answer (score 1):

Right now you're getting the same value for both because your query is returning a set number of rows for each `GROUP BY`, and for each `COUNT()` statement all of those rows are populated, so you are receiving the same value in your results counting over those fields. You need to count the *unique* values of those ids. So change

```
Select 
    deliveryaccount,
    DATEDIFF(d,deliverytime, getdate()) AS ago
    ,COUNT(ex_deliverylog.deliveryid) as session
    ,COUNT(ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryid) as recipients
```

to

```
Select 
    deliveryaccount,
    DATEDIFF(d,deliverytime, getdate()) AS ago
    ,COUNT(distinct ex_deliverylog.deliveryid) as session
    ,COUNT(distinct ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryid) as recipients
```

If that doesn't satisfy your needs, I'd recommend separating your count of sessions and count of recipients into separate queries that you feel you have more control over.

Comment: Now both fields (session & recipients) return sessions count.

Comment: In that case you need to refactor your query, and it sounds like you don't fully understand your own query right now which means you shouldn't trust the results anyway. I don't know what the fields in these tables refer to so the advice I can give you is pretty limited.

Comment: @NimeCloud You are joining on deliveryID.  Unless there is a deliveryID in ex_deliverylog that is not in ex_deliverylog_recipients those counts will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

How can I count both sessions & their total recipients?
Need to count ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryrecipientid

```
SELECT 
        deliveryaccount
       ,DATEDIFF(d,deliverytime, getdate()) AS ago
       ,COUNT(DISTINCT ex_deliverylog.deliveryid) as session
       ,COUNT(DISTINCT ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryrecipientid) as recipients
FROM ex_deliverylog
LEFT JOIN ex_deliverylog_recipients 
       ON ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryid = ex_deliverylog.deliveryid
GROUP BY
    deliveryaccount,
    DATEDIFF(d,deliverytime, getdate())
ORDER BY ago, session desc
```

A person can receive the same email more than once.
E.G. sent to two groups and the person was in each group.
If you need a count of unique recipients then deliveryrecipientaddress (not deliveryrecipientid) :

```
SELECT 
        deliveryaccount
       ,DATEDIFF(d,deliverytime, getdate()) AS ago
       ,COUNT(DISTINCT ex_deliverylog.deliveryid) as session
       ,COUNT(DISTINCT ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryrecipientaddress) as recipients
FROM ex_deliverylog
LEFT JOIN ex_deliverylog_recipients 
       ON ex_deliverylog_recipients.deliveryid = ex_deliverylog.deliveryid
GROUP BY
    deliveryaccount,
    DATEDIFF(d,deliverytime, getdate())
ORDER BY ago, session desc
```

Comment: Perhaps you should *highlight* the difference between the two queries. It took me a while to discern it. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has a nice SQL extension to do this.

Add "`WITH ROLLUP`"  after your `GROUP BY` clause, and it will produce subtotals at each GROUP BY level.